# Wrap text around span - chrome issue

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Open this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5tN73/1/) in Chrome and Firefox (or IE9, Opera) and see differences.

or see Image:

[image]

Can chrome behave like firefox?

Comment: Why you want to do something like this?

Comment: @Stano I know it's an example, but using span over here is a wrong practice, may be he must be trying to get this but in a wrong way

Comment: @Stano can be done better using div's

Comment: these kinds of problems make me think "reset.css" to start with a level playing field before trying to fix browser specific issues

Answer (score 1):

I believe no, it can not. Your best bet is to write this in a way that will look the way you want on Chrome and use that version when you detect whether the user is using Chrome or an other browser. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706196/different-css-files-for-different-browsers) for more details.

OR

You can use code that will look the same or similar in all current browsers. For your example you need to add:

```
<span style="float:left">Test </span>
```

to your text.

Another solution is this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #test{
            position: relative;
            left: 120px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body style="margin:0px; padding: 0px;">

<span style="width: 100px; background:red; float: left; clear: left; height: 4px;" ></span> 
<span style="width: 220px; background:red; float: left; clear: left; height: 4px;" ></span> 

<div id = "test">
<span>Test </span>
</div>

</body>
</html>​​​
```

Comment: float left isn't solution, when I have more text - whole text goes down

Comment: there is no way(that you can implement) that chrome is going to behave the same as firefox. that is obvious to anyone. you need to explain your question more clearly and in detail for anyone to be of help. what do you want the text to do exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Just give the style 'float:left' to the div

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body style="margin:0px; padding: 0px;">

<span style="width: 100px; background:red; float: left; clear: left; height: 4px;" ></span>
<span style="width: 220px; background:red; float: left; clear: left; height: 4px;" ></span>

<div style="float:left">
<span>Test </span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```