# How to provide CSS properties for Different browsers like Mozilla and Chrome

Tags: css, browser

If I would like to give a unique property to a page (say index.html) for different browsers. For example : Blue background for Chrome and Red Background for Firefox, then how can I write a CSS code to this case?

Comment: So, you want yo go back to the 90's and the browsers war? Please, don't even start.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Using CSS Media Queries (Chrome/Safari)

```
@media not all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
{  
    #example
    {
        width: 200px;
    }
}
```

### Chrome/Safari specific css file (Chrome/Safari)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style-sheet_chrome.css" type="text/chrome/safari" />
```

### Here is a CSS Hacks list

```
/***** Selector Hacks ******/

/* IE6 and below */
* html #uno  { color: red }

/* IE7 */
*:first-child+html #dos { color: red } 

/* IE7, FF, Saf, Opera  */
html>body #tres { color: red }

/* IE8, FF, Saf, Opera (Everything but IE 6,7) */
html>/**/body #cuatro { color: red }

/* Opera 9.27 and below, safari 2 */
html:first-child #cinco { color: red }

/* Safari 2-3 */
html[xmlns*=""] body:last-child #seis { color: red }

/* safari 3+, chrome 1+, opera9+, ff 3.5+ */
body:nth-of-type(1) #siete { color: red }

/* safari 3+, chrome 1+, opera9+, ff 3.5+ */
body:first-of-type #ocho {  color: red }

/* saf3+, chrome1+ */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
 #diez  { color: red  }
}

/* iPhone / mobile webkit */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
 #veintiseis { color: red  }
}


/* Safari 2 - 3.1 */
html[xmlns*=""]:root #trece  { color: red  }

/* Safari 2 - 3.1, Opera 9.25 */
*|html[xmlns*=""] #catorce { color: red  }

/* Everything but IE6-8 */
:root *> #quince { color: red  }

/* IE7 */
*+html #dieciocho {  color: red }

/* Firefox only. 1+ */
#veinticuatro,  x:-moz-any-link  { color: red }

/* Firefox 3.0+ */
#veinticinco,  x:-moz-any-link, x:default  { color: red  }



/***** Attribute Hacks ******/

/* IE6 */
#once { _color: blue }

/* IE6, IE7 */
#doce { *color: blue; /* or #color: blue */ }

/* Everything but IE6 */
#diecisiete { color/**/: blue }

/* IE6, IE7, IE8 */
#diecinueve { color: blue\9; }

/* IE7, IE8 */
#veinte { color/*\**/: blue\9; }

/* IE6, IE7 -- acts as an !important */
#veintesiete { color: blue !ie; } /* string after ! can be anything */
```

Answer (score 5):

First up, browser sniffing is bad and you will almost certainly regret doing it.

However, if you must, you could do it server-side like this: [Browser sniffing with .htaccess](http://v4.thewatchmakerproject.com/blog/no-more-css-hacks-browser-sniffing-with-htaccess/)

Ideally though, stick with best practice, which is to use conditional comments in your HTML to handle old versions of IE, and write CSS that deliberately works consistently cross-browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var browser=navigator.appName;
if browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" {
document.write("<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"IE.css\">");
}
else if browser == "Firefox" {
document.write("<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"FF.css\">");
}
else {
document.write("<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"generic.css\">");
}
</script>
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1706221/1087653

Or you can use commands like:

```
<!--[if IE 6]> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="iespecific.css" />
<![endif]-->

<![if !IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="not-ie.css" />
<![endif]>
```

Comment: Wasn't that possible without Javascript?

Comment: The examples in the 2nd box are non-js commands. But this commands are only interpreted by IE. All other browsers handles this command as a simple comment.

Comment: I tried this code in chrome and firefox but both of the time browser's value is Netscape

Answer (score 0):

> `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style-sheet_chrome.css" type="text/chrome/safari">`

This is a bug in WebKit/Blink and Chrome plans to fix it in version 50, so it will no longer work.

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=286682

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/m/#!topic/blink-dev/nH1O6WszMgo