# How do I make a website developed for Firefox browsers compatible with Safari and Chrome?

Tags: html, css, firefox, safari, webkit

To start off, I am not very experienced with web development. I know enough, however when I get to browser compatiblity I struggle. I am trying to figure out why Chrome and Safari are reading my website's code so differently. I understand different browsers read code differently, however I have been trying to figure out how to fix this problem on my website for awhile now and I am unable to.

I'm hoping that I can at least figure out why the menu is on the left in the Safari browser and not on the right like it should be in the Firefox browser. If I figure this out I feel it can help me figure out how to clean up the rest of my code so it looks like it should in the Safari browser. I've been trying to figure out how to implement **webkit** properly, but I do not know how to do so yet.

One reason it may look this way is because I am using Safari on a PC, which may make the Safari version look the way it does on my computer. Below are screenshots of the landing page and how they look on Firefox and Safari:

[Firefox Version (How the website is supposed to look)][1]

[Safari Version][2]

```css
.nav {
  position: fixed;
}

.navbar-fixed-top {
  transition: background-color .25s linear;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.navbar-fixed-top.scrolled {
  transition: background-color .25s linear;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white !important;
  display: initial;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.navigation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ddbe6e;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  z-index: 999;
  transition: all 1s ease-in 0s;
  font-family: bebas-kai, sans-serif;
}

.navigation ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.navigation li a {
  color: #222658;
}

.navigation ul li {
  padding: 30px;
}

#nav-list {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 40px;
}

.navigation.show {
  display: initial;
  animation: fade-in .5s ease-in;
}

#logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  float: left;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin-left: 50px;
  z-index: 1000;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#logo.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  float: left;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin-left: 50px;
  z-index: 1000;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

#logo.scrolled {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  float: left;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin-left: 50px;
  z-index: 1000;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#wrapper {
  background: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 90vw;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#menuTitle {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  color: #222658;
  font-size: 25px;
  user-select: none;
  transition: color .25s linear;
}

.circle {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #222658;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: all cubic-bezier(0.26, 0.1, 0.27, 1.55) 0.35s;
  left: 50px;
}

.top {
  top: 32%;
}

.middle {
  top: 53%;
}

.bottom {
  top: 72%;
}

.icon.close .top {
  top: 48%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.icon.close .middle,
.icon.close .bottom {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 48%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar-fixed-top">
    <a href="index.html"><img id="logo" src="images/core-logo.png" alt="logo" height="46" width="176"></a>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div class="circle icon">
        <h1 id="menuTitle">Menu</h1>
        <span class="line top"></span>
        <span class="line middle"></span>
        <span class="line bottom"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation">
      <ul id="nav-list">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="team.html">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at some documentations about CSS and browser support. [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp) has a very interesting table with all the tags and its compatibilities.

Also, there's an answer that might help you figure out webkits: [How to provide CSS properties for Different browsers like Mozilla and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13118247/how-to-provide-css-properties-for-different-browsers-like-mozilla-and-chrome/13118249)