# Using A Different StyleSheet For Different Browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So far I'm using this JS to load a different stylesheet if one the specified browser. At the moment though, it's not working for me. It doesn't display any of the stylesheets. I cant find whats wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ( $.browser.mozilla == true ) {
  document.write("<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css\FF.css\">");
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if ( $.browser.chrome == true ) {
  document.write("<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css\Chrome.css\">");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Probably because `$.browser` was deprecated (in jQuery 1.3 ?) and removed (in 1.9) from jQuery, what version are you using? And why are you doing this at all, it shouldn't generally be neccessary to load different stylesheets for Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: I'm doing this because the css needs to be different otherwise the content wont look right.

Comment: It is a bad idea to store stylesheets based on browser due to maintainability reasons . As far as i know, if you make something work in firefox , it will surely work in chrome ... but IE will require some efforts

Comment: It works yeah but not how I want it to look in firefox.

Comment: Rather than styling every browser individually (but hey, it's your workload and maintenance nightmare, not mine…) have you tried using a [tag:css-reset] CSS stylesheet to set all elements to a common default, which should account for most Firefox/Chrome differences.

Comment: Here is the useful link

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706196/different-css-files-for-different-browsers][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706196/different-css-files-for-different-browsers

Comment: CSS detection using javascript is here [use this link it is useful][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706196/different-css-files-for-different-browsers

Comment: There is actually a very strong chance that any Firefox "fix" will also work in Chrome, especially if you use a reset stylesheet.  If you do go down the two stylesheets method, make sure that isn't the case.

Answer (score 2):

The comment above is correct that this is no longer a JQuery function.

As you say you are doing this is because the content looks different, try using these tools instead:

- http://modernizr.com/ - will allow you to style by what elements work, rather than what browser you are in
- http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ - will help standardise the default styles of elements
- http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/
- http://validator.w3.org/ - valid code is more likely to work in all browsers.

Failing that, ask the specific question here (ideally using jsfiddle) - it is rare for css not to work on all new browsers or for a simple workaround not to be possible.

Also: it is almost impossible to test in all browsers nowadays as there are so many, so knowing a single script works on everything you have tested should give confidence that it will work on those you have not tested.

Answer (score 0):

This feature was removed in jQuery 1.9: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/

On this page this library is suggested to get this functionality: http://modernizr.com/

Answer (score 0):

Pure javascript version tested on Chrome & Firefox. Should work on Opera. Past on your page where you want. Better if at the bottom before

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",browsercss);

function browsercss() {
    navigator.sayswho = function () {
        var c = navigator.userAgent,
            b, a = c.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || [];
        if (/trident/i.test(a[1])) return b = /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(c) || [], "IE " + (b[1] || "");
        if ("Chrome" === a[1] && (b = c.match(/\bOPR\/(\d+)/), null != b)) return "Opera " + b[1];
        a = a[2] ? [a[1], a[2]] : [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, "-?"];
        null != (b = c.match(/version\/(\d+)/i)) && a.splice(1, 1, b[1]);
        return a.join(" ")
    }();
    var stylesheet = "";

    if (navigator.sayswho.indexOf('Chrome') >= 0) {
        stylesheet = 'http://example.com/chrome.css';
    }
    if (navigator.sayswho.indexOf('Mozilla') >= 0) {
        stylesheet = 'http://example.com/mozilla.css';
    }
    if (navigator.sayswho.indexOf('Opera') >= 0) {
        stylesheet = 'http://example.com/mozilla.css';
    }

    loadcss = document.createElement('link');
    loadcss.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
    loadcss.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    loadcss.setAttribute("href", stylesheet);

    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(loadcss);
}
```

Comment: Would I just put this in the head of my index.html before the stylesheet links?

Comment: Yes, becouse 'append' will add the link at the bottom of head tag ;) Must be included after JQuery...i can make vanilla for include itself

Comment: That won't work, almost every browser known to man has a useragent like `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows something) browser (like Gecko/Chrome)` etc. so you'll  match everything.

Comment: i working on workaround of that thanks for tip adeneo with refulat exp.

Comment: I have tested it and it doesn't work. Am I supposed to change the '+stylesheet+'? Also, I'm guessing I remove the link tags because the append will automatically load on in depending on the browser?

Comment: Must be included after jquery and on domready. I make a jsFiddle soon

Comment: Look at my last comment, I just edited it. Also, what is DOMReady? D: I'm a noob with Jscript

Comment: Include this js on your defualt javascript file after jquery http://jsfiddle.net/StartStep/P8tWJ/1/

Comment: can you add me on skype: bossfakeid - to help me install this.

Comment: I dont like Skype...give an url of the website and i will help you.

Comment: so this goes after the jquery part?

Comment: You can place this updated part wherever you want:  jsfiddle.net/StartStep/P8tWJ/7 becouse it's plain js no jquery required. Tested on Firefox and Chrome. Dont forget to mark my answer as solution. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to detect and change the css for different browsers but the code is a bit bulky.

Use link

[Different CSS files for Different Browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706196/different-css-files-for-different-browsers)